# political downvoting unrelated to a question?

Tags: discussion

Is anything ever done when some people downvote things to make some kind of point that is unrelated to the question?

I made a comment that a question "What is a hostname" doesn't deserve 7 votes, and I downvoted it.  I figured it makes sense and it's consistent with the idea of votes reflecting usefulness of the question for the community. Sometimes I see a question with 0 and I think yes it deserves 0 and I don't upvote it I don't think it deserves it. Sometimes I see a question with -1 and I think it deserves -1.. sometimes I see one with -1 and I think it doesn't deserve -1, and I upvote it to 0.  I may be wrong on that method. But anyhow, I made my comment.

I then see this pattern.  Clicking the vote number, it looks like one person gave one downvote to my last 3 questions as some kind of drive-by revenge!

This of course is not related to the usefulness or uselessness of the question. So I think it's clearly wrong.

Should such a thing be reported?

```
graphby timeby post
-6   Today
-2   34 mins ago    downvote    Good program for displaying video file information?
-2   35 mins ago    downvote    chrome- only auto-fill certain fields?
-2   35 mins ago    downvote    how do I insert audio x seconds into a video?
```

Comment: A Meta.SO post related to the same post/incident http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94078/downvoting-to-compensate-for-many-upvotes-abusive

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Should such a thing be reported?

Reporting is generally not needed since there are automated scripts which will pick up suspicious voting patterns and revert them. If you see this happening on a consistent basis then flag the post with the required explanation, the mods will investigate the issue

Comment: ok, i've never clicked that flag button before.. so a box comes up where you enter an explanation, then click ok and then it gets flagged?  it covers 3 posts really, so i suppose the thing to do would be to flag one post and in the explanation, reference the other two posts?

Comment: @barlop yes, that would be correct.