# dealing with a drive-by downvote by flagging?

Tags: discussion, flagging, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [political downvoting unrelated to a question?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2678/political-downvoting-unrelated-to-a-question)

I thought i was once advised that if I saw i'd been hit with what looks very much like a drive-by downvoter, like a few downvotes in one minute, then I should flag one of the questions and include a note that it and 2 others have just been downvoted.. and a moderator can look at it.

I just looked at the comments on flags i've made, one time I flagged a question or answer for the above reason which I stated, and the flag was declined on the basis that it didn't require moderator intervention.

Comment: You already asked this question before

Comment: I dont think you deserved this, but didnt you yourself say? "What is a hostname" doesn't deserve 7 votes, and I downvoted it.""     And the downvotes you got were on answers that were ?ok answer?  so are you teaching a practice that was retroactivly applied to yourself?  13 hits for realising it was the MsAgent dog making scratching noises ?  It doesnt deserve 13 hits, and it ALSO doesnt deserve to be downvoted for revenge, or to assume it is not worthy of the 13 it got.

Comment: @Psycogeek Well I think the dog answer got votes 'cos it was funny and people liked it for that reason as well as it being good to know and something others missed. Generally regarding me saying a question or answer not deserving x votes, and your example "what is a hostname" which I said that of, I was also judging the quality of the question, it was easy to look up.  No questions or answers should be downvoted for revenge, it happened straight after I gave a downvote to somebody(they then deleted their answer). Questions and answers should be judged individually and not based on other ones.

Comment: If you look at my TOP rep answers, they are also the lamest , least research required also.  When I am Pushing the UP button on peoples questions and answers, I try to keep it simple, It could be a correct solution to the problem, it doesn't have any huge flaws in it.  I did not even know that were supposed to be "arranging the importance of the questions for the community" by downvoting something that is stated correct, is a good question, is a good answer. With thousands of users a mere correct answer should have thousands of votes.

Comment: Downvoting something because it is sort of lame, but totally accurate , isnt doing anyone any good.

Answer (score 3):

It often doesn't require moderator intervention. Moderators will only see it if a [user has downvoted you over 5 times.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3461515#3461515)

If someone has down voted you a bunch of times, a task runs every once and a whole by the system that will fix your reputation, and penalize the voter. This is known as "serial downvoting."

Basically, the system takes care of this for the most part, not moderators

Comment: Do you have a reference for moderators not having this information?

Comment: @DanielBeck No, hence the `from what I know`, as I'm sure I've heard it before. I will get a reference as soon as I can ask a moderator in chat.

Comment: the system doesn't always spot it. There is a process that corrects it or recalculates rep or something and maybe is run nightly i'm not sure. It certainly doesn't always pick it up.  In my case it hasn't corrected it, though maybe it hasn't run yet.  i've had a moderator tell me they don't have information but can initiate running the thing to recalculate rep, i didn't know they do have the info if a user downvotes over 5 times, but I suppose they do!

Comment: @barlop you can do a rep recalc yourself at superuser.com/reputation

Comment: Mods don't have access to specific vote information. @DanielBeck

Comment: @Sathya Not specific, but starting with 5 downvotes from user A to user B, you can see it.

Comment: @DanielBeck no - we can't see who's voted on what. All we can see is vote clusters - eg: if user A has voted 90% of his votes on user B - we can see *that* pattern but not specific votes

Comment: @Sathya That's what I meant. If I complain about 5+ downvotes, you can get a list of candidates.